# Switch From Solr To Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

I have a website whose core module is search. The search engine primary work on parameters (i.e nontext searches) and I am using solr for it.

**Issue I faced:** CPU utilization goes high as I have a complex sort and sometimes have the large number in in query.
Even when I switched from solr4 to solr5 or solr6, performance do not improve

I am thinking to use Elastic Search. Will this be beneficial?

Data details:

```
Site : Dating Site
Data : 800k Male, 500k Female
Solr Used : 4 (under ha proxy)
```

Queries Like: filter (age= , height= , city = .... around 20 such parameters) and sorting (reverse preference matching)

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing your data model/mappings, the queries you're running, the amount of data you have and the number of nodes (and spec's thereof) you're running...

Comment: @ val please check

Answer (score 0):

The question is where your bottle neck. Both ElasticSearch and Solr use Lucene under the covers. So, if it is actually search performance that is the issue, then you are unlikely to get a performance boost.

I would suggest instead that you try to profile your installation first and then join the User Mailing list to help you tune. For example, there are many Query Parsers in Solr that may help in specific scenarios. Or maybe you need docValues for specific fields.

The question does not have enough information to answer, but - in general - jumping from Solr to ElasticSearch (or the other direction) will not automatically improve your performance without a lot of in-depth profiling of what you have first.